# Tesseract 4.1.1 error eng.traineddata not found in google colab

Tags: ocr, google-colaboratory, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am trying to install tesseract 4.1.1 in google colab. I have installed tesseract and I can check the version using `!tesseract --version`. After that I have download eng.traineddata and org.traineddata in the `/usr/local/share/tessdata/` folder

Now when trying to use it from python it's giving me the following error

```
TesseractError: (1, 'Error opening data file /usr/local/share/tessdata/eng.traineddata Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to your "tessdata" directory. Failed loading language \'eng\' Tesseract couldn\'t load any languages!)
```

I have tried to check the file exist or not using this

```
if os.path.isfile('/usr/local/share/tessdata/eng.traineddata'):
    print ("File exist")
```

which prints `File exist`. Any help regarding that will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what packages have you tried, but i'll put my solution to use in google collab

1. First install tesseract-ocr

   `!sudo apt install tesseract-ocr`
2. Install tesserarct with pip

   `!pip install pytesseract`
3. Set your environment folder

   `import os
   os.environ['TESSDATA_PREFIX'] = '/usr/share/tesseract-ocr/4.00/tessdata/'`
4. (Optional) If you want another language other than english(i.e fr or esp), you have to install using this, in my case I used japanese language

   `!apt-get install -y language-pack-ja
   !export LC_ALL=ja_JP.utf8
   import locale
   !apt-get install -y tesseract-ocr-jpn`
5. Check your language is installed (your code), english is installed by default, but following my case is

   `import os
   if os.path.isfile('/usr/share/tesseract-ocr/4.00/tessdata/jpn.traineddata'):
     print ("File exist")
   else:
     print("Nope")`
6. Once all it's configured you can run the code

   `import pytesseract
   import shutil
   import os
   import random
   try:
     from PIL import Image
   except ImportError:
     import Image
   from google.colab import files
   uploaded = files.upload()
   '''here you can delete the lang atribute because english is by default, in my case i uploaded an image named "2.png"'''
   extractedInformation = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('2.png'), lang="jpn")
   print(extractedInformation)`

I hope that can help you

Answer (score -1):

Try this command

```
export TESSDATA_PREFIX=/usr/local/share/
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing and why you believe it is the best approach?